# Can F# JSON type provider use units of measures?

Tags: json, f#, units-of-measurement, type-providers

I am using F# JSON type provider to parse structures that contain data about radio and TV programs. The data may come from different sources and therefore contain timing information expressed in different units - frames in seconds, milleseconds etc.

Currently I am doing all conversions in code after obtaining a parsed object, but it would be very nice to be able to hint JSON type provider about measures of certain fields. I haven't found any information about whether this possible.

Is it?

Comment: That would be the job for a deserializer. A type provider infers types from content and Json has no concept of units. The CSV provider generates units because it checks the header text for unit-like strings like `(meters)`

Comment: Of course raw JSON doesn't have any concept of unit, but this means that parsed data can't be used per se, they have to be run through the adapter that will enrich them with units. I was looking for a way to simplify this process.